# rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io, upgrade their nodes to the latest avaliable version

Tags: ink, smart-contract, rococo

Does anyone know when the `rococo-contracts-rpc.polkadot.io` is going to upgrade their nodes to the latest available version ?

Error:

[image]

Ink version:
[image]

Comment: We really need this as well.

Comment: It should be updated now. Is this still an issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If our cargo-contract is version 3.0.1 it would work like a charm.

[image]

If our cargo-contract is version 3.1.0 (which was [yanked](https://github.com/paritytech/cargo-contract/issues/1239#issuecomment-1653580989)) or above  it would not work.
[image]